# How to find the reverse-inorder successor in a binary search tree

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am fairly new to programming. I've managed to get the inorder successor for any given node in a BST. But I can't figure out how to get the successor in case or reverse-inorder. In inorder the keys are printed in ascending order. So, in case of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, The inorder successor of node 2 will be 3. But for the same BST, the reverse-inorder will look like: 5, 4, 3, 2, and 1. And reverse_inorder successor of 4 will be 3. How do I accomplish that in code. Please help.

And the tree maintains a parent pointer too.

```
typedef struct Node 
{
    int key;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
    struct Node* parent;
}Node;

void reverse_inorder(Node* root)
{
    reverse_inorder(root->right);
    printf("%d ", root->key);
    reverse_inorder(root->left);
}

Node* inorder_successor(Node* root, Node* n)
{
    if (n->right != NULL)
        return find_min(n->right);
 
    NodeObj* p = n->parent;
    while (p != NULL && n == p->right) {
        n = p;
        p = p->parent;
    }
    return p;
}

Node* reverse_inorder_successor(Node* root, Node* current)
{
   // What goes here?
}
```

The function `reverse_inorder` prints the nodes in descending order. How do I find the successor in this case?

Comment: Invert the tree. And then do regular inorder. You can find invert tree function online without issues.

Comment: Or, in reverse_inorder, the successor would be the next smaller key in order? So that means you are looking for predecessor in a regular BST in the end?

Comment: Or, you don't need to invert the tree. You can still use inorder traversal but instead of going to left node first, you start with right node, then you process the data, and then the left node.

Comment: @Faraz I can't modify the tree itself. So inverting the tree is not an option. But is successor in inverse_inorder is the same as predecessor in normal inorder for any given BST in all cases?

Comment: yes it is the same. Also, Assalam o Alaikum. Also, you will have to confirm this with the professor. I am 95 percent sure it is.

Comment: Walaikum Salam. You've been a great help. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you confirm this assumption with the professor or friends.